# Tag synonyms: Sealed class

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, synonym-request

There are few tags related to sealed classes, and most of them don't even have a description:

- 183x [sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sealed): *"The sealed modifier keyword prevents a C# class from being inherited. Similar to the final keyword in Java."*
- 143x [sealed-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sealed-class)
- 18x [java-sealed-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-sealed-type)
- 18x [kotlin-sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin-sealed)

I suggest merging them into a single tag [sealed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sealed).

Comment: The "usage" description for [[tag:sealed]], at the moment, makes it appear to be about the keyword, not the feature it provides. I'd suggest that if these are merged, the usage description is updated before hand, as the description could be read to use the tag [[tag:final]] when asking about Java (I am not suggesting this is correct).

Comment: @ThomA "...makes it appear to be about the keyword, not the feature it provides" - does it serve a purpose to make that distinction, anyway? I can't fathom why.

Comment: The fact I made the comment can be read as me saying it does serve a purpose, @KarlKnechtel , for the reason I detail. According to the description `sealed` is not a Java keyword for this feature, yet the OP suggests that the java tagged is merged in.